# Django Custom User Model Best Practice: User = get_user_model()?

Tags: django

I'm trying to create a custom user class and I'd like to know the best practice for implementing referencing the new user. After following the Django docs method of implementing the custom user as follows in models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

And settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
```

And admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import User

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

The Django docs say to use settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL in place of user specifically for ForeignKeys and OnetoOneField, but it's not clear about other instances.

My question is specific to how to refer to the custom user class in views.py. Before defining the user class I was using

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

But after defining a custom class this is no longer correct. I've seen boilerplate code use this method in the beginning of views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()
```

Is this the best practice for referencing the custom user? Or should I just be using settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL in place of where I previously had User?

Comment: I'd say it is to keep the code future proof, as you can re-use your code without keeping track of the classes' names, although I doubt they will change the User model's name in a near future. Also the docs also say it's not recommended to create your own custom User class but rather use a FK, unles you really need to.

Comment: I thought it was the opposite, that the official recommendation is to create a custom user class just in case. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project

Comment: After about django 1.7 I pretty much always future proof by creating a custom user model. In version 1.6 or less the workarounds and recommendation were a lot different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL will load the user class lazily after all django apps are loaded. Calling get_user_model() on a module level when your app is initially loaded may result in that the user model app is not loaded and also circular imports.

### Update: I read two specific questions:

**How to correctly access the user model, contrib or custom.**

Djangos get_user_model() is quite simply a call to [django.apps get_model()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/contrib/auth/#get_user_model) using the `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`. If you are writing apps that might be reused in other projects with other user models, use the get_user_model call. Always. Then it doesn't matter what the user model is.

If you have created your own `core.User` model and is very confident that your code will only be used in this project, `from core.models import User` works as well.

**When to use the string representation from settings instead of fetching the model.**

The string representation will in the end usually call the same django.apps get_model() anyway. By giving a string instead of the class itself in Foreignkeys, OneToOneFields etc you simply don't require the model to be looked up during django app imports, where the user model may not yet be available. So using string representation is simply deferred loading of a model. The same goes for all models.

An also during djangos different major versions this behavior have changed, which is another topic. Notice that get_user_model() have been updated in Django 1.11 for import usage.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model

Comment: I edited the question so it's more direct. So would implementing this just be a matter of replacing all "Users" with settings.AUTH_MODEL_USER?

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 5):

you can go with `get_user_model` instead `User`

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()
```

`get_user_model` will **Returns the User model that is active in this project.**

if you modify(adding new field into it) default `User` table you need to use `get_user_model`  it will return active User table.

BTW `User` will return native from `django.contrib.auth.models`